# Enforce authentication for firebase-storage downloadable urls

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Firebase docs suggest that [obtaining a downloadable url](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) (e.g. for streaming video in html `<video>` tag) is done by `getDownloadURL()`, on any storage reference. Thus, you can set security rules which will be applied for client requests via the SDK.

However, it seems that the downloadable URL received is publicly available to any client/device, with no authentication required.

Is there any way to enforce security authorization for such use case? I notice you can revoke the public URL manually in the console, but it's not a scalable solution, nor secure.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to download a file from Firebase Storage:

- `gs://bucket/object`
- `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucket/o/object?token=<UUID>`

The former is an internal reference, and can be used to upload and download files via our SDKs. These are protected by Firebase Authentication and Firebase Storage Security rules. It is designed to be used by users of your application, while in the application.

The latter is an external reference, and can be used only to download files that have been shared, usually external to the application. Since the user who this has been shared with is outside of your application, there's no way they could authenticate, so authorization is less interesting.

The authorization we provide is "do they have a long unguessable token" that means someone authorized to share the file with them gave them permission to. This is commonly known as a "public, unguessable URL" or a "signed URL" due to the cryptographic signing that's often used to convey certain claims (like how long the URL is valid, what operations it's valid for, etc.).

We believe that there's little sense in making an "external" representation that can only be used by "internal" app users, though I'd be open to hearing your use cases if you disagree.

Comment: Thanks. My use case is simple- i'd like to have a video-on-demand service, which means that only upon firebase authentication i will provide the video url. So any authenticated user can just copy the video url directly from the source, and pass it around. Revoking manually the token is just not a scalable solution.

Comment: Yup, just use the first method which is basically this.

Comment: Just to add to what @MikeMcDonald has said. Google obviously have faith in this system as this is how many of their file sharing systems work. Google Phots is one such example. Here is an interesting article explaining this: [link](https://www.theverge.com/2015/6/23/8830977/google-photos-security-public-url-privacy-protected).

Comment: unguessable token... it is a guid lmao

Comment: @MikeMcDonald thanks for your response but  I am unsure how this solves the problem. The flutter video player expects a url to play a video. How can we provide an internal url to this video player so that anyone seeing this url cannot access the video

Comment: @LawrenceO you can either download the entire video via the first URL and then provide a local URI to play the video, or you can stream the video from a public unguessable URL in the second. If you wanted, you could modify the flutter video player, but I don't know how much effort that would be.

Comment: We have a very real requirement for External links being used by authenticated users. Our app is a workflow system for people who work with media. The nature of the work is that it deals with media that is sensitive in nature - it should not be accessible outside of the app. We use thumbnails for these using standard <img> elements with signed URL's. It would be great if we could restrict these links to authed users only. We have our own solution that can serve images based on header auth - but would prefer to keep it in one place