# Is there any way to revoke public download url generated from private url on firebase storage programmatically?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-storage

Recently I am developing an app which connects to firebase and upload important documents to firebase storage.

There are users who will view uploaded documents, so I generated download URL after upload document and stored download url into firebase database so that the app will get download url and use it.

Btw, once generated download url, it is public so anyone can use the link to view the uploaded document on firebase storage.

So I decided to store private url of document into firebase database and then once valid user wants to view the document, the app will generate download url from private url and then use the link to show to the user.

And then right after viewing, I want to revoke download url of the document programmatically on the app.

I see I can manually revoke download url on firebase storage on browser, but I want to do it programmatically on my app.

For security, this is very important.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

There currently is no public API to revoke download URLs from Cloud Storage for Firebase. The only way to revoke download URLs is through the Firebase console.

I recommend that you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Related:

- [Firebase revoke token on download url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626687/firebase-revoke-token-on-download-url)
- [Revoking Firebase storage download urls](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ta#!topic/firebase-talk/aw86jf8b7PY)

Comment: Thanks for your attention to my question.
In this situation, is there any way to secure uploaded documents stored on firebase storage?

Comment: Download URLs are no longer auto-generated (they used to be), and can only be generated by someone who already has access to the file. I'm not sure what other security you're looking for here.